# Why Glide loads images only for the second time? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using adapter to display the list of profile icons. I am using glide to display the images. But problem is, it loads default profile and not loading the url from response for the first time.

When I go to previous page and comes to the page second time, it loads the url.

#### Code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RetailerStatusViewHolder holder, int position) {

    if(retailerList.getImgUrl()!=null){
      Glide.with(context) 
            .load(retailerList.getImgUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_profile)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_default_profile)
            .into(((holder.circleImageView)));
    }
}
```

I tried by giving `context.getApplicationContext()` too but still images loads only second time

#### Gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

#### XML:

```
<com.customviews.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/recycle_profile"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_default_profile"/>
```

Comment: `Glide` take some time to load image from url

Comment: Glide take some time to load an image, and it also creates problem when you load in Circular  `ImageView` [See this link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1026) it will help you to find out problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**XML code:**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<alpha
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
```

**Java class:**

```
public static void loadImage(final Activity context, ImageView imageView, String url, int placeHolderUrl, int errorImageUrl) {
    if (context == null || context.isDestroyed()) return;

    //placeHolderUrl=R.drawable.ic_user;
    //errorImageUrl=R.drawable.ic_error;
    Glide.with(context) //passing context 
            .load(getFullUrl(url)) //passing your url to load image.
            .placeholder(placeHolderUrl) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
            .error(errorImageUrl)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
            .animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
            .fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView 
            .into(imageView); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.
}
```

**Add this line in your activity:**

```
Utils.loadImage(YourClassName.this,mImageView,url,R.drawable.ic_user,R.drawable.ic_error);
```

**In fragment:**

```
Utils.loadImage(getActivity,mImageView,url,R.drawable.ic_user,R.drawable.ic_error);
```

I think it helps you